# Loop through basic array knowing the total count

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to convert an array like this

```
_Array = @[[[feeds objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey: @"title"],
           [[feeds objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey: @"title"],
           [[feeds objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey: @"title"],
           [[feeds objectAtIndex:3] objectForKey: @"title"],
           [[feeds objectAtIndex:4] objectForKey: @"title"],
           [[feeds objectAtIndex:5] objectForKey: @"title"],
           [[feeds objectAtIndex:6] objectForKey: @"title"],
           [[feeds objectAtIndex:7] objectForKey: @"title"],
           [[feeds objectAtIndex:8] objectForKey: @"title"],
           [[feeds objectAtIndex:9] objectForKey: @"title"],
           [[feeds objectAtIndex:10] objectForKey: @"title"],

           [[feeds objectAtIndex:xx] objectForKey: @"title"]];
```

Into a loop. I know the total count of the array. And have been trying something like this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < dCount; i++) {
    [[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey: @"title"];

      }
```

But unsure how to add the loop to the array.

Thanks

Comment: @Josh I'm not sure I agree with this particular duplicate. This question is asking how to use a loop. The duplicate is asking how to do it without a loop. While this question can be solved without a loop (as in my answer and in the duplicate), this question doesn't ask that.

Comment: Since I knew that the loop wasn't the best way to do this, I probably erred on the side of solving the problem rather than answering the question here, @rmaddy; I make no objection if you want to reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are asking is how to use a loop to add elements to the `_Array` array, correct?

Try this (assuming `_Array` is `NSArray` and `feeds` contains dictionaries):

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dict in feeds) {
    [tmpArray addObject:dict[@"title"]];
}

_Array = [tmpArray copy]; // make it immutable
```

An even simpler way, using KVC, is:

```
_Array = [feeds valueForKey:@"title"];
```

BTW - standard naming convention states that variable and method names should start with lowercase. Consider changing `_Array` to `_array`.

Update for the comment:

You would need to use a similar loop as the first part of my answer:

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dict in feeds) {
    NSString *imagePath = [[empty stringByAppendingPathComponent:dict[@"image"]] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    [tmpArray addObject:imagePath];
}
_images = [tmpArray copy];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly to solve the issue above, thanks so much mate, but created a couple of other issues, how would I use your method for an array like this...

     _images = @[[[empty stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[feeds objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey: @"image"]] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]],......

Comment: See my update to handle the `_images` array.

Comment: You are my hero. Thanks rmaddy. Just for others you might want to edit the "addObject:image" to "addObject:imagePath"